# Passing Observable to sibling component in RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to pass a Javascript Object as an Observable to a sibling component.
To do so, I created a service `pass.service.ts` that contains a variable declaration as follows:

`public passedData:any`

```
this.fb.user$.subscribe(data => {
    this.passservice.passedData = of(data);
})
```

By doing so, I can subscribe to the observable in my other component.
I am retrieving the data in the other component using:

```
this.passservice.passedData.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data
})
```

I am not getting any new updates, once `data` changes though.

The behaviour is the same as if I'd subscribe by using `Observable.first()`

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean *"once the observed data changes"*? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: The other component is subscribed to a *totally different object*, then.

Comment: I did another edit.
I am aware that this is another object.
This is necessary in my example.
I am subscribing to an Observable and using the observed data to create another one.
Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You are creating an observable with `of(data)` and never again emitting from that observable. This is expected. If you do `let arr = [1, 2];` `const obs = of(arr)` and then `arr.push(3)`, subscribers to `obs` won't recieve the 3rd element.

Comment: If you know that then it's not clear why thought this *would* work, use a subject instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) (Subjects are also Observables). `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';`

**Service**

Create a Subject in your service. This Subject will be used by your components to share data.

```js
public passedData = new Subject<any>();
```

**Component 1**

Pass new data into the Subject by calling `next`.

```js
this.passService.passedData.next(data);
```

To pass all events including `error` and `complete` events from one Observable to a Subject you could do: `this.fb.user$.subscribe(this.passService.passedData);`
But this will mean `this.passService.passedData` just mirrors `this.fb.user$` and you could just aswell use `this.fb.user$` directly instead.

**Component 2**

Get notified about new data from the Subject by subscribing.

```js
this.passService.passedData.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subject makes more sense, or perhaps inject this.fb to your service if you are using dependency injection

```
this.passservice.passedData=new Subject()
this.fb.user$.subscribe(this.passservice.passedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just define the property in your service as this:

```
user$ = this.fb.user$;
```

Then you could subscribe to it in any component that needs it.

But it actually looks like you already have another service (fb?) that has a user$ property? If so, you could subscribe to that user$ property in each component that needs it.

You could also pipe it through a `shareReplay(1)` to share the result with all subscribers:

```
user$ = this.fb.user$.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

I put together an example of passing a stream to a child component here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-deborahk-child